# Font-family CSS transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I want to get a hover animation that changes the font-size and font-family the same time. I didn't manage to change back the font family **precisely when** the font-size transition has finished. Is this even possible?

[image]

What I have:

```
a{
 -webkit-transition: font-size .2s ease;
 -moz-transition: font-size .2s ease;
 -o-transition: font-size .2s ease;
 -ms-transition:font-size .2s ease;
 transition: font-size .2s ease;
}

a:hover{
 font-family: "MyHoverFont";
 font-size: 3em;
}
```

What I tried:

```
a{
 ...
 -webkit-transition: font-family.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: font-family .2s ease;
 -o-transition: font-family .2s ease;
 -ms-transition: font-family .2s ease;
 transition: font-family .2s ease;
}

a:hover{
 ...
 font-family: "MyHoverFont"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use **animations** or **transitions** with `font-family`. This means, you actually can do this, but it would change the `font-family` immediately instead of morphing from one `font-family` to another.

But I found a good workaround for this ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/29bbnd/is_it_possible_to_animate_fontfamily/)):

> You could do the following: have two divs, each with the same text but
>   different font. The second div is absolute positioned below the first
>   div and hidden by default. When the times comes to "morph" the font,
>   animate the first visible div opacity to 0, and the second div to 1.
>   It should look like it's morphing at the expense of a little more
>   convoluted mark up.

**Hint**

It seems like you do something like the following:

```
 a {
   ...
   transition: font-size .2s ease;
   ...
   transition: font-family .2s ease;
 }
```

But in this case, the second rule overwrites the first rule, so the following is what you usually do:

```
transition: font-size .2s ease, font-family .2s ease;
```

Comment: I know this is a little old, but I would add that, since font-family doesn't transition, it might be more 'correct' to use a transition delay instead. Something like `transition: font-size .2s ease, font-family 0s ease 0.2s;`. That way the code is a little clearer in terms of what the desired behaviour is.

Answer (score 7):

Modern browser now support [Variable fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/Variable_Fonts_Guide) where you can control the available font's settings.

You could also go to [this example](https://jsbin.com/venipic/edit?css,js,output) for controlling the settings.

```js
var changes = [
  "'CASL' 1, 'MONO' 1, 'wght' 758, 'slnt' -14",
  "'CASL' 0, 'MONO' 0.24, 'wght' 481, 'slnt' -2" 
];

// style="font-variation-settings: ... "
text.style.fontVariationSettings = changes[1];

// Change variation every 2 sec
var index = 0;
setInterval(function(){
   text.style.fontVariationSettings = changes[index];
   index = index === 0 ? 1 : 0;
}, 2000);
```

```css
@font-face{
 font-family:"Recursive";
 src:url("https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/0fb48cf42677cf004e48f2608a8521a4ca06b48d/8a39e/assets/fonts/recursive-mono_casl_wght_slnt_ital--2019_11_05-00_13.woff2") format("woff2-variations");
 font-weight:300 900;
 font-display:swap
}

#text{
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: Recursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.5s font-variation-settings ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">Hello World</div>
```

Not all font and options is supported, if you want to find some variable font's resource you could go to [this link](https://variablefonts.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65680948/css-transition-with-fonts) that I raised in Stack Overflow.
The Javascript demo is at:
https://www.cqrl.in/dev/font-transition-js.html
The GitHub code is here:
https://github.com/Sukii/font-transition
The TUGBoat paper is here:
https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb42-1/tb130venkatesan-transfont.html

Comment: This is a really interesting research but it uses svg which makes transitioning various font families a challenge. Maybe this is the reason why we don't have native transitions between two different font families even today. We only have Variable fonts at the moment but it is limited to transition within itself only.

Comment: Yes, SVG is too general and there are simple homotopy transformations that create one-dimensional skeletons of fonts which should be the starting point of defining a font. There has been considerble work on parametrizing using PANOSE numbers, not taken-up by the generative AI/ML world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant version font, because font-variant uses a mathematical formula for transitions that css transition understands:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant