# CSS transition with fonts

Tags: javascript, css, latex, svg-animate, metafont

This is a tricky question:
Does CSS transition with fonts work with font-weight and font-family?
See for example:
https://www.cqrl.in/dev/font-transition.html

This is actually a Donald Knuth MetaFont question that will make Douglas Hofstadter smile!
Is there any hope of doing it through Canvas/SVG/SVG-font or some such thing?
If you think of them as curves it is topologically a simple homotopy deformation.

Comment: This could be worth looking into: https://opentype.js.org/

Comment: The question is assuming you have the letter forms, how do we do the smooth transition from one form to another?

Comment: Thanks Robby for pointing out the tremendous JavaScript work on openype font.

Comment: For the transitions there's a couple of SVG/Canvas path tweening/morphing libraries out there that might help, but I don't have any experience with any of them myself.

Comment: Yes, I found one that is pretty interesting here: https://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/

Comment: It's all fun and games until you try to morph between two paths with a different number of vertices, which is likely to be the case when switching between font families (or even font weights).

Comment: You can always resample both the curves to provide equidistant points along the path of the curve (usually donated as "s"), assuming one can obtain the other by a simple homotopy transformation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple-homotopy_equivalence

Comment: Raphael of course comes quite handy at handling SVG paths (https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/)

Comment: See Chapter 13: Metafont, Metamathematics, and Metaphysics: Comments on .Donald Knuth's Article "The Concept of a Meta-Font". in Douglas Hofstadter [Metamagical Themas](https://www.amazon.in/Metamagical-Themas-Douglas-Hofstadter/dp/0465045669)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Font transition solution using Javascript opentype.js and raphael.js library

Along with the hint given in
https://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/
I was able to cook-up something that is preliminary here:
https://cqrl.in/dev/font-transition-js.html

Pushed the code to github:
https://github.com/Sukii/font-transition

Comment: This preliminary solution only works for the case when the font glyph is topologically singe connected disc.

Comment: Code has been updated to work for for characters with holes like O,Q,A, P, R etc. and also by fluke for B (which has two holes).

Comment: It now also works for glyphs with two holes like B and g.